# how to run a html file with python and mongodb for backend

Tags: python, mongodb, rest, eve

I am having a login.html for which I use python for validation purpose and I am using mongodb for storing the values. I have created my API using EVE REST Framework. I want to know how to run the html file so that i could validate the user. The python file is running on http://127.0.0.1:5000

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The link provided will be valid only on your machine as it is clearly a localhost IP. You will have to either will a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) link or add the code to the question.

Comment: Do you have an endpoint for your login.html page? Like, can it be accessed by `localhost:5000/login` ?Visit that. If not, create that. Look into the docs of your framework. And what you think is your python file running on localhost, is actually your development applications server.

Comment: @bad_keypoints you were right i did not create an end point, can you guide me on how to create an endpoint for login.html. My settings.py holds the schema for my db collections.
Thank you

Comment: @TonyRoczz I'll give you three links to go through, to help you find your solution, since I'm not versed well with your framework (having never used it before). [The quickstart here](http://python-eve.org/quickstart.html) does give you an example of setting the endpoints in settings.py, goes into detail about it. For more extensive configuration, [follow this link](http://python-eve.org/config.html). [Account management configuration goes here](http://python-eve.org/tutorials/account_management.html)

Comment: I have already studied those pages and i couldn't run it properly

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this](http://eve-sqlalchemy.readthedocs.org/en/stable/tutorial.html#authentication-example) (search for `flask login view`) This should help you create `/login` endpoint.
From your login.html, you need to call this URL with appropriate data (username and password is used in the example)